# not able to use dojo widgets in opensocial gadget inside apache shindig container

Tags: dojo, apache-shindig

I am not able to use dojo widgets in my open social gadget. Here is the steps i followed
1. I am using apache shinding in tomcat 6.0.29 in my local machine. Tomcat is running on default port 8080.
2. This is the gadget xml

```
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
 <link rel="stylesheet" ....type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/local/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
    function loader () {
        dojo.require ("dijit.Editor");
        dojo.addOnLoad(callback);
    }

    function callback () {
        new dijit.Editor ({}, dojo.byId("editorNode"));
    }

    dojo.config.parseOnLoad = true;
    dojo.config.dojoBlankHtmlUrl = '/blank.html';
    dojo.addOnLoad(loader);
</script>
<div id="editorNode" class="tundra">Hello, xcc world!</div>

    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

1. I am testing this gadget in the default samplecontainer of apache shindig.
   I tested in google chrome and i am getting the following error in the javascript console

   Origin http://127.0.0.1:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
   Uncaught Error: Could not load 'dijit.Editor'; last tried '../dijit/Editor.js'

Comment: The dojo path in the code above is http://localhost:8080/samplecontainer/dojo1.5/dojo/dojo.js     entire error trace                                      XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/gadgets/concat?container=default&gadget=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsamplecontainer%2Ftest_local.xml&debug=0&nocache=1&type=js&1=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsamplecontainer%2Fdojo1.5%2Fdojo%2F../dijit/Editor.js. Origin http://127.0.0.1:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're getting a cross-domain permission error.  What this means is that you cannot load the editor dijit because dojo tries to load it with Ajax (and Ajax cannot access resources on a different domain).  As silly as this sounds, 127.0.0.1:8080 is considered a different domain from localhost:8080.

Therefore, instead of accessing your shindig server from http://127.0.0.1:8080, try accessing it from http://localhost:8080.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This issue can be resolved by using a cross domain build of dojo.